# Javascript I want to delete an element

Tags: javascript

I want to use the specifications shown in this video, but it does not work.
Please confirm it.

https://gyazo.com/0dd4feeea3f7a27aefe6d2160944c65e

Conditions:

- You can delete the task when you press the delete button
- ID is reassigned when deleting a task
- After deleting, when adding a new task, the IDs are serialized

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Todoリスト</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Todoリスト</h1>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked="checked">全て
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="2">作業中
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="3">完了
    </p>
<p></p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>コメント</th>
        <th>状態</th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody class ="addTask-target"></tbody>
    </table>
    <h2>新規タスクの追加</h2>
    <input class="addTask-value" type="text" />
    <button class="addTask-trigger" type="button">追加</button>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</script>
</html>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const addTaskTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-trigger')[0];
    const addTaskTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-target')[0];
    const addTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-value')[0];  
    let nextId = 0;
    const todos = [];

const addTask = (task,id) => {
    //テーブル要素を生成する　td要素を作る
    const tableItem = document.createElement('tr');
    const addButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
    const idSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
    const taskSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
    const removeButtonTd = document.createElement('td');

    //Button要素を生成する
    const addButton = document.createElement('button')
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button')

    //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
    addButton.innerText = '作業中';
    removeButton.innerText = '削除';
    idSpanTd.innerText = id;
    taskSpanTd.innerText = task;

    //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
    tableItem.append(idSpanTd);
    tableItem.append(taskSpanTd);
    tableItem.append(addButtonTd);
    tableItem.append(removeButtonTd);
    addTaskTarget.appendChild(tableItem);

    //生成したbutton要素を生成する
    addButtonTd.append(addButton);
    removeButtonTd.append(removeButton);     

    const todo = {
        task: 'taskSpanTd',
        status: '作業中'
    };
    todos.push(todo);

};

addTaskTrigger.addEventListener('click',() => {
    const task = addTaskValue.value;
    addTask(task,nextId ++);
    addTaskValue.value = '';
});

const element = document.querySelector('td')
document.getElementById("removebutton").onclick = function() {
element.remove();
};

});
```

Comment: And the question is? What is your exact problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to delete an element, but I can't. The following error code is output.

main.js:53
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property'onclick' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: `document.getElementById("removebutton")` can you show me in your code where is such button with such ID?

Comment: PS: you **cannot** have duplicated IDs in your document. You should use Class instead.

Comment: I did not understand... what should happen with the IDs on delete?

Answer (score 0):

- Define your buttons *click* actions upon buttons creation
- Use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to handle your `todo` `"status"` property and reactively apply changes to the TR element classList
- Use [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) - you don'w want empty spaces to become new todo tasks.
- preferably use always `Element.textContent` instead of `Element.innerText`
- When deleting your TR element, don't forget to update the `todos` Array by removing that item using `todos.splice(todos.indexOf(todo), 1);`

```js
// Helper functions
const ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);

// Todo App
const EL_list = EL('#todo-list');
const EL_task = EL('#todo-task');
const EL_add = EL('#todo-add');
const todos = [];
let id = 0;

const addTask = () => {

  const task = EL_task.value.trim(); // Always trim!
  if (!task) return; // Do nothing
  
  EL_task.value = "";
  id += 1;
  
  const todo = {
    id: id,
    task: task,
    status: "",
  };
  
  // Make "status" reactive
  Object.defineProperty(todo, "__status", {
    set(val) {
      this.status = val;
      TR.classList.remove("is-done", "is-doing");
      TR.classList.add(`is-${this.status}`);
    }
  });
    
  todos.push(todo);
  
  // New Elements
  const TR = ELNew("tr");
  const TD_id = ELNew("td", {textContent: id});
  const TD_task = ELNew("td", {textContent: task});
  const TD_status = ELNew("td");
  const TD_remove = ELNew("td");
  
  const EL_btn_doing  = ELNew("button", {
    className: "todo-btn-doing",
    textContent: "Doing",
    type: "button",
    onclick() {
      todo.__status = "doing";
    }
  });
  
  const EL_btn_done  = ELNew("button", {
    className: "todo-btn-done",
    textContent: "Done",
    type: "button",
    onclick() {
      todo.__status = "done";
    }
  });
  
  const EL_btn_remove = ELNew("button", {
    textContent: "×",
    title: "Remove this task",
    type: "button",
    onclick() {
      if (!confirm(`Remove task ID:${id} "${task}"`)) return; // Do nothing
      TR.remove(); // Remove element
      todos.splice(todos.indexOf(todo), 1); // Remove from todos list
    }
  });

  // Insertions
  TD_status.append(EL_btn_doing, EL_btn_done);
  TD_remove.append(EL_btn_remove);
  TR.append(TD_id, TD_task, TD_status, TD_remove);
  EL_list.append(TR);
};

EL_add.addEventListener("click", addTask);
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/* {margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table th, 
table td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#todo-list tr.is-doing td {
  background: #fb0;
}

#todo-list tr.is-done td {
  background: #0fb;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#todo-list tr.is-doing .todo-btn-doing {
  color: #fb0;
}

#todo-list tr.is-done .todo-btn-done {
  color: #0fb;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="todo-list"></tbody>
</table>
<h2>Add new Todo</h2>
<input id="todo-task" type="text" />
<button id="todo-add" type="button">Add</button>
```